# Jquery Ajax throws syntax error on 404

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a ajax call to the server to check if the server running. When it is, I get a JSON as a response.

However, when the server is down and there is a 404, this is the response I am getting : `<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>404 - Not Found</body></html>` as a string.

The `ajaxConvert` is trying to handle the response as a JSON and when it gets a string, its throwing a syntax error as it couldn't parse it.

Do I have to set the dataType in ajax to `text/json` ?

Comment: Do you have control of the back-end?

Comment: @Akar Nope. However, if you have something to add to the backend, can you please let me know as it would be really helpful to have the idea.

Comment: You could send the response as a JSON from the backend, so then you can parse it simply using JavaScript. for example you could return an error object `{error: true, errorCode: 404}`. so then in the Javascript you could check for it.

Comment: There's a number of possible issues here - the `404` response when the server is down is normal / accurate response, but it's possible to (on the server side) throw any error code you want. Also, the server side code could be sending you improperly formatted json objects (as strings) which would cause this error. Or you could be parsing it incorrectly. Can you post your parsing code or a simplified model version and what you expect as a response object?

Comment: if the server was actually down you wouldn't be getting a page in first place.

Comment: @derloopkat - That's right, apologies. Words can be tricky. Unless the OP expands they're explanation, and based on the framing of the post it seems like it's server-side issues, I'm not sure how to help :(

Comment: I am getting the following information in the network tab:Request URL:url
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 
Remote Address:[::1]:443

Comment: @derloopkat I alrady have an error handler, however it is throwing this json parsing error when going through the ajax internal call

Comment: please include your code in the question.